# Matplotlib won't plot: dbus issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, dbus

I have a rather strange scenario.  I'm running on a very old installation, so I've compiled most of the tools I use.

First, this is a server.  It is exclusively used by SSH-ing into it.  But whoever set this server up made some strange choices.  Instead of creating separate users, there is one user on login called fphyiscs, with a home directory of /home/fphysics.  (Access is controlled strictly via public key/private key authentication.  So everybody logs in as "fphysics", but there are no passwords.)  Then there are "profile" directories in this one.  For instance, mine is /home/fphysics/joelfred.  There is a script that is run by fphysics on login that looks through the directories in /home/fphysics and interprets these as "profile".  You can then choose which "profile" you want to use.  The script then sources a file called "ENVS" in this profile directory.

I thought this was weird.  But I know better than to argue with a sysadmin.  So I work within this system.  I set up my ENVS to source a more conventional .bash_profile, instead of just setting up environment variables as they probably intended.  I set my HOME environment variable in ENVS: export HOME=/home/fphysics/joelfred.  The software on this system is so outdated that I've compiled tons of my own stuff, using a prefix of $HOME/opt.  So my path now includes $HOME/opt/bin.  I sym-linked /home/fphysics/.Xauthority to /home/fphyiscs/joelfred/.Xauthority, so x sessions work over SSH.  I honestly don't remember all the hacky things I've done to make this work more normally, and so I can have access to more current software.  (For instance, GCC is v4.1.2, copyright 2006.)

I've since tried to compile and install Matplotlib, with the GTK3Agg backend.  This means, of course, that I had to compile a lot of x libraries, GTK, pygobject, etc., etc.  At some point along the line, I had to compile DBUS.  Now, I have some interesting/annoying Matplotlib behavior.  This, for instance, works as expected:

```
fphysics@facet-srv01 ~$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 30 2013, 00:58:45)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

** (ipython:1648): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-oWyQu0DxxF: Connection refused

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)

In [4]: y=x*x

In [5]: plt.plot(x,y)
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xacb2eec>]

In [6]: plt.show()
```

This works as expected - I get a plot of a parabola.  I get a window that blocks my ipython terminal.  The window, as far as I can tell, has full functionality.  When I close it, I get returned to my ipython terminal.  Note the strange dbus error though - I have NO IDEA where it gets the /tmp/dbus-oWyQu0DxxF idea.  I've looked and I don't get it.

Okay.  So now I want to turn on interactive mode:

```
fphysics@facet-srv01 ~$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 30 2013, 00:58:45)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

** (ipython:4181): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-oWyQu0DxxF: Connection refused

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: plt.ion()

In [4]: x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)

In [5]: y=x*x

In [6]: plt.plot(x,y)
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb0f1fcc>]
```

I get nothing.  Weird.  I try a show:

```
In [7]: plt.show()
```

Nothing.  I try a draw:

```
In [8]: plt.draw()
```

I get a window with a title of "Figure 1", but it's gray.  I try another draw:

```
In [9]: plt.draw()
```

Now I get a window with my parabola.  But no buttons work.  I can't even close the window.  So I try a close:

```
In [10]: plt.close()
```

Nothing happens.  Okay.  I'll exit my ipython terminal:

```
In [11]: exit
```

Window goes away, no errors.  But what happens if I don't do a show or a draw or just exit?  I get weird errors:

```
fphysics@facet-srv01 ~$ ipython
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 30 2013, 00:58:45)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.13.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

** (ipython:7262): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-oWyQu0DxxF: Connection refused

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: plt.ion()

In [4]: x=np.linspace(-10,10,100)

In [5]: y=x*x

In [6]: plt.plot(x,y)
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb636bf6c>]

In [7]: exit
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py", line 87, in destroy_all
    manager.destroy()
  File "/home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 415, in destroy
    self.canvas.destroy()
AttributeError: FigureManagerGTK3Agg instance has no attribute 'canvas'
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_pylab_helpers.py", line 87, in destroy_all
    manager.destroy()
  File "/home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3.py", line 415, in destroy
    self.canvas.destroy()
AttributeError: FigureManagerGTK3Agg instance has no attribute 'canvas'
```

So I dug into dbus - the only error I can see that may be affecting things.  I have two installations apparently:

```
fphysics@facet-srv01 ~$ $HOME/opt/bin/dbus-daemon --version
D-Bus Message Bus Daemon 1.7.2
Copyright (C) 2002, 2003 Red Hat, Inc., CodeFactory AB, and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
fphysics@facet-srv01 ~$ /bin/dbus-daemon --version
D-Bus Message Bus Daemon 1.1.2
Copyright (C) 2002, 2003 Red Hat, Inc., CodeFactory AB, and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Maybe they're competing?  I don't know.  I've symlinked /home/fphysics/.dbus to /home/fphysics/joelfred/.dbus.  That doesn't seem to help.  I'm at a loss.  I have no idea what's going on.  How do I diagnose this?  How do I get dbus to work in my scenario?  How do I test it on a more basic level?  What in the world is going on??

BTW, Ipython makes the testing easier, but the behavior is the same if I run from a python prompt.

Comment: I think you are having event loop issues with the gui (that is why the buttons don't work, the strange behavior with draw).  The error on exit is because the figures are being torn down in the wrong order (again probably related to the event loop).  I think the dbus error may be a red-herring.

Comment: also, that is a terrifying setup

Comment: This doesn't help at all, but I feel your pain.  "I'm running on a very old installation, so I've compiled most of the tools I use." <-- That sounds painfully familiar... At least from the looks of it, it's RHEL5 instead of something even older?  Until recently, I was stuck working primarily with RHEL3 machines. Getting modern code to compile on ancient systems can be a nightmare...

Comment: What do you get with a quick `psearch dbus-daemon`?  You should see  two different dbus-daemons running, one system-wide and one for your user. Is there an additional one running? If so, it probably is a conflict of some sort.

Comment: @tcaswell - Interesting about the even loop issues with the gui - how would I go about diagnosing this?  Is there some super-extra-verbose mode I can turn on that should catch those errors?

Edit:  And yeah - totally terrifying.  There's some weird stuff about how some things treat home folders and paths and things, like that .xauthority symlink.

Comment: I only know because I had event loop issues with some QT stuff, I know nothing about gtk.  Sorry, the best I can do is maybe point you in the right direction.

Comment: @JoeKington What `psearch` command??  I don't have it, I'm not sure which one you're referring to...

Comment: @Joel - If you don't have psearch, you can use `ps uax | grep dbus-daemon | grep -v grep` instead.

Comment: @Joel - I just realized that I said "psearch"... I meant `pgrep`.  "psearch" is an alias that I have set for slightly nicer display. I was half awake yesterday!  At any rate, something like `ps -fp $(pgrep dbus-daemon)`, though piping `ps`'s output through `grep` also works.

Comment: @JoeKington Oh look at that, there are three...

`fphysics   828  0.0  0.0   2912   532 ?        Ss   Apr30   0:00 /home/fphysics/joelfred/opt/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 4 --print-address 6 --session

dbus      3447  0.0  0.0   2848   968 ?        Ss   Mar08   0:00 dbus-daemon --system

fphysics  6409  0.0  0.0   2848   884 ?        Ss   Mar25   0:00 /bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 11 --print-address 14 --session`

Comment: @JoeKington Now I need to figure out why fphysics is running /bin/dbus-daemon, don't I?

Comment: So I compiled on a separate machine where I have sudo.  I didn't use sudo, and I got the exact same behavior.  So maybe this is not a supported method of install for matplotlib using the Gtk3 backends?  And I mean exact: down to the socket it's looking for, /tmp/dbus-oWyQu0DxxF, which I thought would be a randomly-generated thing.  If it's showing up on a separate system after compilation, I think maybe it's a deeper problem?

Comment: Did we ever figure out why this is happening?

Comment: @Pwnna I haven't.  I don't think anybody else has either, as far as I know.